# Get URL path or node.id in views fields replacement pattern

Tags: views, 8, path-aliases

I need to rewrite my view fields like:

```
<a href="{{ path }}">
 <div class="card-header">
   <h3 class="card-title">
     {{ title }}   
   </h3> 
 </div>
</a>
```

But if I click on *Add field* (in my view), `nid`, or `path` are not available? I have to construct my `<a>` link attribute like above markup. But how do I render the URL path to the node?

Answer (score 1):

> But if I click on Add field (in my view), nid, or path are not
>   available?

Did you create a view of [Show: Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5ZcT.jpg) ? (re-using pic from other answer, look in view settings)

You probably selected something else, hence why those fields are not available.

So you could add a relationship of node content or create a brand new view again and this time make sure you select Show: content.

Comment: In my view I am loading Solr indexed fields. I figured out the solution by Checking Retrieve result data from Solr in the solr server configuration (Advanced tab). After checking this box I am able to use {{ url }} in my view.